# WSO2 APIM 2.0 Clustering deployment issue when deploy sample API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

After i deployed APIM 2.0 in one server with 2 pubstore nodes, 2 key manager nodes, 1 gateway manager and 2 gateway worker nodes i login to publisher and deploy sample API, but i encounter such error and failed to deploy it:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-29 00:25:55,799] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error in adding API :PizzaShackAPI (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#108)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_5(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:108)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_39(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:124)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_3(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:390)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:21)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error in adding API :PizzaShackAPI
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:647)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:1059)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_createAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:964)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:1063)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:2348)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:600)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Error in associating lifecycle for the artifact. id: a6637158-0f26-460e-86a5-c3cc0c67c1d4, path: /apimgt/applicationdata/provider/admin/PizzaShackAPI/1.0.0/api.
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.attachLifecycle(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:396)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:2294)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Couldn't find aspectName 'APILifeCycle'
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.associateAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2469)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.associateAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:499)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.associateAspectInternal(UserRegistry.java:1901)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3800(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$39.run(UserRegistry.java:1873)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$39.run(UserRegistry.java:1870)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.associateAspect(UserRegistry.java:1870)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.attachLifecycle(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:383)
    ... 73 more
 {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag}
```

Any clue for the root cause?

Comment: Is the user a tenant one or super tenant one?

Comment: I did NOT config multiple tenant support.

Comment: This can happen due to many reasons. Corrupted data in the databaseis one of them. Can you try clearing database and restart with `-Dsetup` option? What is the database you're using. I assume registry mounting configurations are done properly. Please double check anyway.

Comment: I used oracle, let me try to clear the registry database first.

Comment: after database recreation, the sample API is deployed successfully. but when i generate access token, i encounter "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Comment: Replied to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen due to many reasons. Corrupted data in the database is one of them. If that is the case, clearing database might fix the issue.

Comment: I used existing database for distributed & cluster deployment, then i encounter such issue. Thx!